# Redirect internal links to subdirectory with .htaccess (for test site)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, subdirectory

Have looked for an answer for a while here but nothing works so far. Basically a site has been installed in a subdirectory of web root, but all the internal links point to the web root, as this is how it is set up on the live site. Is there an htaccess rule to redirect all internal links to the subdirectory, or another way of making the links work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding these rules to the htaccess file in your **document root** (the web root):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/subdirectory%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/subdirectory%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ /subdirectory%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

If you want to redirect those request, change the square bracket flags to: `[L,R=301]`

Comment: That works, thank you. I assume the third line in your code was meant to have `-d` at the end not `-f`. Could you briefly explain the purpose of the first RewriteCond?

Comment: @user1697563 Yeah, that was a typo. Fixed. The first 2 conditions checks if the given request doesn't map directly to a file (`!-f`) nor a directory (`!-d`). And the next to conditions check if we added a `/subdirectory` in front of the given request, whether it would map to an existing file (`-f`) **no** an existing directory (`-d`).